# Cannot correctly pretty print entire JSON array with JSON libraries in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing, pretty-print, org.json

I have an unformatted JSON string which I want to format using Java. I already added the `org.json` dependency and I wrote the following code:

```
String json = "[{...}, {...}]"; // Placeholder for my actual large JSON array string
JsonArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
json = jsonArray.toString(4);
```

After formatting, the JSON became much smaller than it should be (originally ~10MB, after formatting ~3MB).

Why? Clearly, a lot of data is missing.

I also tried `Gson` but it failed with

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'java.io.Reader#lock' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.
    at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:38)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:286)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:556)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:294)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:556)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:834)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:812)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:759)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:736)
```

since I'm using Java 19.

Used code:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(json));
jsonReader.setLenient(true); // Enable lenient mode to handle malformed JSON
json = gson.toJson(jsonReader);
```

Finally, I tried `Jackson`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(mapper.readTree(json));
```

Same problem as `org.json`, the output JSON is about 1/3 of the original.

Comment: What data is missing?

Comment: It's likely that your source has problems like duplicate keys in objects. Some JSON parsers will throw those out silently. For example, Jackson has `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY` but I'm not sure if it's enabled by default.

Comment: One easy way to find out what's different could be to *not* enable pretty printing, then `diff`ing the input and output files.

Comment: A minimal example that would allow use to see the problems in these three bits of code would really help.

Comment: Okay, I realized I screwed up while concatenating JSONs from different requests into a single big JSON. That was my mistake. Now formatting is working fine with e.g. `Jackson`. `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY` did not help, the JSON parser still ran successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake ended up being that I concatenated different JSONs into a big JSON in the wrong way by doing e.g. `"[{...}, {...}]" + "[{...}, {...}]" ...`
Of course, that didn't work correctly and JSON parsing stopped after the first array as expected. After fixing my concatentation logic, even the 10MB JSON is parsed and formatted correctly using e.g. the `Jackson` library.